# Hadoop Pig - Replace strings in a relation with their corresponding values in a map

Tags: apache-pig

I have a relation called conversations_grouped made up of bags of tuples of varying sizes, like so:

```
DUMP conversations_grouped:
...
({(L194),(L195),(L196),(L197)})
({(L198),(L199)})
({(L200),(L201),(L202),(L203)})
({(L204),(L205),(L206)})
({(L207),(L208)})
({(L271),(L272),(L273),(L274),(L275)})
({(L276),(L277)})
({(L280),(L281)})
({(L363),(L364)})
({(L365),(L366)})
({(L666256),(L666257)})
({(L666369),(L666370),(L666371),(L666372)})
({(L666520),(L666521),(L666522)})
```

Each L[0-9]+ is a tag corresponding to a string. For example, L194 might be "Hello, how are you doing?" and L195 might be "fine, how are you?". This correspondence is maintained by a map called line_map. Here's a sample:

```
DUMP line_map;
...
([L666324#Do you think she might be interested in  someone?])
([L666264#Well that's typical of Her Majesty's army. Appoint an engineer to do a soldier's work.])
([L666263#Um. There are rumours that my Lord Chelmsford intends to make Durnford Second in Command.])
([L666262#Lighting COGHILL' 5 cigar: Our good Colonel Dumford scored quite a coup with the Sikali Horse.])
([L666522#So far only their scouts. But we have had reports of a small Impi farther north, over there. ])
([L666521#And I assure you, you do not In fact I'd be obliged for your best advice. What have your scouts seen?])
([L666520#Well I assure you, Sir, I have no desire to create difficulties. 45])
([L666372#I think Chelmsford wants a good man on the border Why he fears a flanking attack and requires a steady Commander in reserve.])
([L666371#Lord Chelmsford seems to want me to stay back with my Basutos.])
([L666370#I'm to take the Sikali with the main column to the river])
([L666369#Your orders, Mr Vereker?])
([L666257#Good ones, yes, Mr Vereker. Gentlemen who can ride and shoot])
([L666256#Colonel Durnford... William Vereker. I hear you 've been seeking Officers?])
```

What I'm trying to do now is parse through each line and replace the L[0-9]+ tags with their corresponding text from line_map. Is it possible to make references to line_map from within a Pig FOREACH statement, or is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Could you add a sample of line_map?

Comment: can you post the result of `DESCRIBE line_map` and `DESCRIBE conversations_grouped`, i.e. the schema of both these aliases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue with this is that in a map the key must be a quoted string. So you can't use a schema value to access the map. E.G. This **will not work.**

```
C: {foo: chararray, M: [value:chararray]}
D = FOREACH C GENERATE M#foo ;
```

The solution that comes to mind is to FLATTEN conversations_grouped. Then do a join between conversations_grouped and line_map on the L[0-9]+ tag. You'll probably want to project out some of the extra fields (like the L[0-9]+ tag after the join) to make the next step faster. After that you'll have to regroup the data, and massage it into the correct format.

This won't work unless each bag has it's own unique ID for the regrouping, but if each of the L[0-9]+ tags appear in only one bag (conversation) you can use this to create a unique id.

```
-- A is dumped conversations_grouped

B = FOREACH A {
    -- Pulls out an element from the bag to use as the id
    id = LIMIT tags 1 ;
    -- Flattens B into id, tag form.  Each group of tags will have the same id.
    GENERATE FLATTEN(id), FLATTEN(tags) ; 
    }
```

The schema and output for B is:

```
B: {id: chararray,tags::tag: chararray}
(L194,L194)
(L194,L195)
(L194,L196)
(L194,L197)
(L198,L198)
(L198,L199)
(L200,L200)
(L200,L201)
(L200,L202)
(L200,L203)
(L204,L204)
(L204,L205)
(L204,L206)
(L207,L207)
(L207,L208)
(L271,L271)
(L271,L272)
(L271,L273)
(L271,L274)
(L271,L275)
(L276,L276)
(L276,L277)
(L280,L280)
(L280,L281)
(L363,L363)
(L363,L364)
(L365,L365)
(L365,L366)
(L666256,L666256)
(L666256,L666257)
(L666369,L666369)
(L666369,L666370)
(L666369,L666371)
(L666369,L666372)
(L666520,L666520)
(L666520,L666521)
(L666520,L666522)
```

Assuming that the tags are unique, the rest is done like:

```
-- A2 is line_map, loaded in tag/message pairs instead of a map

-- Joins conversations_grouped and line_map on tag
C = FOREACH (JOIN B by tags::tag, A2 by tag)
    -- This generate removes the tag
    GENERATE id, message ;

-- Regroups C on the id created in B
D = FOREACH (GROUP C BY id) 
    -- This step limits the output to just messages
    GENERATE C.(message) AS messages ;
```

Schema and output from D:

```
D: {messages: {(A2::message: chararray)}}
({(Colonel Durnford... William Vereker. I hear you 've been seeking Officers?),(Good ones, yes, Mr Vereker. Gentlemen who can ride and shoot)})
({(Your orders, Mr Vereker?),(I'm to take the Sikali with the main column to the river),(Lord Chelmsford seems to want me to stay back with my Basutos.),(I think Chelmsford wants a good man on the border Why he fears a flanking attack and requires a steady Commander in reserve.)})
({(Well I assure you, Sir, I have no desire to create difficulties. 45),(And I assure you, you do not In fact I'd be obliged for your best advice. What have your scouts seen?),(So far only their scouts. But we have had reports of a small Impi farther north, over there. )})
```

**NOTE:** If at worst, (the L[0-9]+ tags aren't unique) you can give each line of the input file(s) a sequential, integer id before you load it into pig.

**UPDATE:** If you are using pig 0.11, then you can also use the [`RANK`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#rank) operator.

Comment: I think the break and regroup idea is a good one. Is there any way that I could add an index to each bag? perhaps create a column that has 1, 2, ... conversations_grouped.length() and JOIN that to conversations_grouped?

Comment: Not that I can think of off the top of my head. But, are the L[0-9]+ tags unique to a conversation? So if L194 is in one line in conversations_grouped, can it show up in another line?

Comment: Sweet! Then make sure to read over my answer again.  I've updated it with a solution that relies on the tags being unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Instead of relying on the tags being unique, I ran with your idea of appending a conversation ID to each bag. The RANK statement was quite helpful.